# How can I create an image gallery?

Tags: 7, views, javascript, media

Currently I am running in D7 with the following modules:

- Media 7.x-2.0
- Views 7.x-3.7
- Colorbox 7.x-2.4

I am trying to create an image gallery using these modules with the following steps. Please note problems I am running into will be in bold.

1. Go to admin/structure/views
2. Click Add new view
3. Select File for show, and image for type
4. Unchecked Create a page, and check Create a block
5. Select Grid of File for Display Format
6. Click Continue and Edit

This is where things go off the rails for me, what I would like to do is have ALL images that are tagged display in a custom image style I already created (200x200) in a 4 column grid, and when you click on them they open up into a normal sized image colorbox.

Now I have seen this done when you create a image content type, but that way is clunky compared to using the media module, and I have to believe that there is an easy way to do this with these modules, and I am simply missing it.

I have read about Media Gallery module, but there seem to be a lot of errors with it and I am not thrilled with the idea of it.

Any help on how to get what I am trying to do done would be greatly appreciated as this is becoming a bother.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in bold but is the issue showing the image in your custom style or having it open in a modal?

For the latter, opening the image in a modal, you would need to set one field item to be the colorbox trigger.

The trigger needs to be a field you have already added, in your case the image field which you will use the custom display format with. Then you add the image field again with the desired popup format. You set this field to display within the colorbox trigger.

There are several related screencasts on drupal.org that may help:

https://drupal.org/project/colorbox

Answer (score 0):

When you add image field in your view there in settings you will have to make **colorbox(formatter)** and for on click pop up select **Colorbox image style**
Configure your view settings.